# unwanted behaviour in StringTokenizer

Tags: java, android, tokenize

I have a String `Result = "FFF-556-GHH-788;DDR4TG441"`. I use StringTokenizer to split the string on delimeter ';'. But the 2 sub-Strings I get are `1->"FFF-556-GHH-788"` and `2->"DDR4TG441DDR4TG441DDR4TG441"`. Why is String 2 repeated 3 times?

code:
main:

```
datum = parseResult(Result);
```

fun:

```
public QRResultData parseResult(String Result)
    {
        QRResultData data = new QRResultData();
        StringTokenizer multiTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(Result, ";");

        if(multiTokenizer.hasMoreTokens())
        {
            data.busNumber = multiTokenizer.nextToken();
        }

        if(multiTokenizer.hasMoreTokens())
        {
            data.seatNumber = multiTokenizer.nextToken();
        }
        return data;
    }
```

Comment: *StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the split method of String*

Comment: Check what exactly you are passing in Result String.

Comment: I cannot reproduce it. `StringTokenizer multiTokenizer = new StringTokenizer("FFF-556-GHH-788;DDR4TG441", ";"); Log.i(TAG, multiTokenizer.nextToken()); Log.i(TAG, multiTokenizer.nextToken());` logs "FFF-556-GHH-788" and "DDR4TG441"

Answer (score -1):

Odd, when I ran your code it works. Can you verify that the code in your question matches the code in production?

```java
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class So66650493 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String Result = "FFF-556-GHH-788;DDR4TG441";
        final QRResultData datum = new So66650493().parseResult(Result);
        System.out.println("datum = " + datum);
        // datum = QRResultData{busNumber='FFF-556-GHH-788', seatNumber='DDR4TG441'}
        if ("FFF-556-GHH-788".equals(datum.busNumber)
                && "DDR4TG441".equals(datum.seatNumber)) {
            System.out.println("SUCCESS parsed correctly");
        } else {
            System.out.println("FAIL");
        }
    }

    public QRResultData parseResult(String Result) {
        QRResultData data = new QRResultData();
        StringTokenizer multiTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(Result, ";");
        if (multiTokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
            data.busNumber = multiTokenizer.nextToken();
        }
        if (multiTokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
            data.seatNumber = multiTokenizer.nextToken();
        }
        return data;
    }

    private static class QRResultData {
        String busNumber;
        String seatNumber;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "QRResultData{" +
                    "busNumber='" + busNumber + '\'' +
                    ", seatNumber='" + seatNumber + '\'' +
                    '}';
        }
    }

}
```

My earlier suggestion to replace StringTokenizer with String.split will not help you much. But it would make your code slightly more legible.

```java
public QRResultData parseResult(String Result) {
    QRResultData data = new QRResultData();
    String[] split = Result.split(";");
    data.busNumber = split[0];
    if (split.length > 1) {
        data.seatNumber = split[1];
    }
    return data;
}
```

Comment: Not really an answer is it.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to offend anyone with my short answer. I have attempted to improve it.

Comment: Ok, I am getting the string result from QRCode; looks like some problem in Qrcode encoder

Comment: Can you say what the real input is? And the real expected output?